# initializing main.py variable into another file

Tags: python

I have two modules:

Main:

```
variable1, variable2 = 800, 800
```

Other:

```
import main
variable1, variable2 = main.variable1, main.variable2
```

I tried to use import main to access the mains variable, however this will reinitialize the entire main class. That is contrary to what I want. I only want a single value from the variable 1 and variable two into this other file without initialization. What can I do?

When I comment out:

```
#from main import DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H
```

It will run the map for example.[RPG Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHwJp.png)

When I uncomment, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Downloads/Programming/Python/Programs/Learning Basics/Program 7.12 - 2D pygame, Snow/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Weather
  File "D:\Downloads\Programming\Python\Programs\Learning Basics\Program 7.12 - 2D pygame, Snow\Weather.py", line 2, in <module>
    from main import DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H
  File "D:\Downloads\Programming\Python\Programs\Learning Basics\Program 7.12 - 2D pygame, Snow\main.py", line 143, in <module>
    Weather.initialize_weather()
AttributeError: module 'Weather' has no attribute 'initialize_weather'
```

This implies I provided no attribute, however note this, I used dir(Weather), to find my problem:

```
['DISPLAY_H', 'DISPLAY_W', 'MAX_RAIN', 'MAX_SNOW', 'RAIN_SIZE', 'Rain', 'Random', 'SNOW_SIZE', 'SPEED', 'Snow', 'SystemRandom', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'betavariate', 'choice', 'choices', 'expovariate', 'gammavariate', 'gauss', 'getrandbits', 'getstate', 'initialize_rain', 'initialize_snow', 'initialize_weather', 'lognormvariate', 'normalvariate', 'paretovariate', 'pygame', 'rainfall', 'randint', 'random', 'randrange', 'sample', 'screen', 'seed', 'setstate', 'shuffle', 'snowfall', 'triangular', 'uniform', 'vonmisesvariate', 'weibullvariate']
```

Then again with the main uncommented:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'pygame']
```

Its erasing my values?

In weather

```
import pygame
from main import DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H
from random import *

DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H = 800, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
```

In main:

```
import pygame
import glob
from random import *
from pygame import mixer
import TileSheet
import Button
import Weather

# Load Window
pygame.init()
# 800x800 pixels
DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H = 800, 800
canvas = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test Tileset')
running = True
```

Comment: What do you mean by reinitialize ? And they are just `modules`, not `classes`.

Comment: importing main RERUNS the entire main module, so i cant for example use import main or from main import variable1. I have to use a specified number for BOTH classes, but I already defined them into the main class, so I want to duplicate this value. So when i go back and change the main value, they will BOTH change.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if i got it, but the `modules` are only run to completion only once. Unless you forcefully `reload` it. And how are you going to change the values in `main.py` ?

Comment: I will show you.

Comment: Could you please paste the code ? You seem to be importing `Weather` in `main.py` and `main` in `Weather.py`, which is kinda creating a cycle. Maybe you want to reconsider that first ?

Comment: You might have a point about that, but the main class MUST have the weather class, the weather class only needs two values for the screen height and width.

Comment: Maybe create a third file(could be a config file too) and `import/load` the display height and width from that in both the `main.py` and `Weather.py` ?

Comment: I don't see how thats sufficient for resources.

Comment: Well, for one, that could solve the cyclic import issue, you seem to have. But i don't understand what do you mean by sufficient for resources.

Comment: I haven't seen one 2D rpg game that did that. Neither professionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `if __name__ == "__main__":` in your `main.py` file.

For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Hello')
```

In the example above program will print `Hello` only if you run `main.py` from that module directly and it won't print anything when you import `main.py` in other modules.

[Read this for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: where do i add this?